# Don't get the right value from dynamically created checkboxes in php

Tags: php

I have this dynamically created checkboxes, which I would like to get some data out off, so I can put into my DB. I have just discovered that, that the checkboxex seems not to Work, as I catches the wrong checkbox or something.

The checkboxes looks like this:

```
<td align="center">
<input name="e10[]" type="checkbox" <?php echo $checked = $foo['e10'] == '1' ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "";?> onclick="document.getElementsByName('e11[]')[<?php echo $tæller-1;?>].value = this.checked ? '<?php echo date('d-m-Y');?>' : '';" value="0" />
<input type="text" class="listform" style="width:60px;" name="e11[]" value="<?php echo sqltoalmdatetom($foo['e11']); ?>">
```

And on my submit page, I have tried this:

```
echo "0=>".$_POST['e10'][0]."|";
echo "1=>".$_POST['e10'][1]."|";
echo "2=>".$_POST['e10'][2]."|";
```

The problem is, that when I only have checked e10[1], then it will show up as it was e10[0]. If I check them both I'll get the right result. What can I do to get the right value, when the first element isn't checked?

--------- update ---------
So now I can get the value, but how do I use it in my mysql update statement?

I'm running through my lines ($etape), as each checkbox is on it's one line. When I need the fields for the update, I was hoping I could use $_POST[e10], but I can't do that now can I?. Each line has a dynamic number, in this case starting at 0, so the checkboxes would be named $_POST[e10[i*line number*]]

```
        for ($j=0; $j<=count($etape); $j++) {
        //Vi går kun videre hvis etapenavnet er udfyldt. 
        //Sikre at der ikke oprettes en tom etape, og at man ikke kommer til at slette etapenavnet
        if ($_POST['e1'][$j] != "") {//e1 == etapebeskrivelsesfeltet
            //Så længe vi ikke er kommet til den nye etape/række, så opdatere vi bare de gamle
            if ($j < count($etape)) {
                foreach ($keys as $feltnavn) {
                        //echo $feltnavn;
                        $værdi = $_POST[$feltnavn][$j];
                        $querys[] = "`".$feltnavn."` = \"".addslashes($værdi)."\"";
                        if ($feltnavn == "e25") {
                            $test_e25 = $værdi;
                        }
                        if ($feltnavn == "e3") {
                            $test_e3 = $værdi;
                        }

                }
                if ($test_e3 && $test_e25) {
                    echo $tmp = 'UPDATE `etape` SET '.implode(', ', $querys).' WHERE id = '.$etape[$j].'  AND ordre_id = '.$tilbudsnummer;

                    echo "<br><br>";
                    unset($querys);
                    //mysql_query($tmp) or die(mysql_error());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When submitting a form, only checked checkbox values will be submitted along. That means you can't use numeric indexes with checkbox arrays to determine which checkbox has been checked.
Use an array with string key values instead. Example

HTML:

```
<input name="e10[i0]" type="checkbox" value="0" />
<input name="e10[i1]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input name="e10[i2]" type="checkbox" value="2" />
```

PHP:

```
if (is_array($_POST['e10']) {
    foreach($_POST['e10'] as $key => $value) {
        $numeric_key = intval(ltrim($key, 'i'));
        echo "$numeric_key => $value |";
    }
}
```

Comment: I managed to solve it using your solution. I'm checking for which checkbox with 
if ($feltnavn == "e4") {
 if (is_array($_POST['e4'])) {
  foreach($_POST['e4'] as $key => $value) {
   if (ltrim($key, 'i') == $j) {
    $ekstra4 = ", e4 = ".$value."";
   } 
  }
 }
}

That is just one, got a few more then this one.

Then later I check for var $ekstra4, if it's set. If not I set it.

if (!$ekstra4) {
 $ekstra4 = ", e4 = 0"; 
}

I then put the var into my query, and get it to update either with 0 or 1, depending on the specific checkbox being checked.